# Change UICollectionViewCell label textColor on orientation changes in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change the colour of a UILabel inside a UICollectionViewCell when the device orientation changes. How can I achieve this.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(deviceOrientationDidChange),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
```

I wanted to observer orientation changed notification inside of the cell but i though it's not right, because there would be no way to remove the observer.
The question is if I observe orientation changes in view controller, how do I get a reference to the UICollectionView cells inside the notification selector to change the cell's label textColor?
This is what I was tried to use:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CommentCell {
    cell.displayNameLabel.textColor = .white
    cell.commentLabel.textColor = .white
}
```

but i can only access one cell view that indexPath. When I set an Int variable and set it value inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, nothing happens because it holds the value of the last item.

Comment: Basically you want to change a label text color when orientation changes. In all the cells ? or particular  cell ?

Comment: all the collection view cells

Comment: You need to manage that thing in `cellForItem` check my answer. Remove your observer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in cellForRowAt

```
 if(orinatedLogic)
 {
         cell.displayNameLabel.textColor = .white
         cell.commentLabel.textColor = .white
  }
  else
  {
         cell.displayNameLabel.textColor = .blue
          cell.commentLabel.textColor = .blue
  }
```

and reload the collection whenever orientation changed

Comment: I added this code inside of ```override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {``` it worked but some cells don't change color, how do i fix this?

Comment: that's because some cells are not currently visible so nil , add a bool value to model array of collectionview with true/false orientation value and reload the collectionView

Comment: what do you mean add a bool value to model array?

Comment: yeah, i've fixed it... i forgot to add the code to determine the colours in cellForRowAtIndexPath that will apply to new cells that weren't visible before. thanks

Comment: update orinatedLogic in oberver call back and reload the collection

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of possibilities depends on you requirements. I assume you don't want to reload entire collection view. 
But you can enumerate all visible cells and either reload them,

```
collectionView.reloadItems(at: collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)
```

or change them directly.

```
collectionView.visibleCells.flatMap{ $0 as? CommentCell}.forEach {
    $0.commentLabel.textColor = ...
}
```

Comment: I added this code inside of override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) { it worked but some cells don't change color, how do i fix this?

Comment: Try to figure out why. Perhaps you doing it to soon, before rotation applied to collection view and all required cells displayed. Don't forget to setup new cells with required parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For Orientation change you can simply add

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

       collectionView.reloadItems(at: collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)

}
```

In your collection view cell for item

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "item", for: indexPath) as! YourCellType

    cell.displayNameLabel.textColor = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait ? .white : .red

    cell.commentLabel.textColor = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait ? .white : .red

}
```

That's It , You did it !!

Comment: `func reloadItems(at indexPaths: [IndexPath])`, so you can provide all  indexPathsForVisibleItems  at once.

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov Didn't get you

Comment: your answer worked, but kind of affecting the constraints for the internal subviews of the cells when I switch back to portrait

Comment: @OluwatobiOmotayo  Yes it might affect.  As Orientation changes bounds of screen you need to take care of it. . By the way if your purpose fulfilled you can mark answer as accepted so it may be helpful to others :)

Comment: do you have a tip on handling the changes in bounds of screen during orientation change

Comment: @OluwatobiOmotayo It depends which constrains you have provided to cell. You can create new question

Comment: I'm also changing the width of the collectionview for different orientation, that's why. so i need a way to layout the subviews again after orientation changes

Comment: @OluwatobiOmotayo you reverse your vote .   My answer was not helpful to you?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Storyboard you can use **Vary for traits** to change your label colour depending upon the orientation.[image]

Comment: i'm not using storyboard